# Unable to start docker container and run command OCI Runtime Create Failed

Tags: docker

I'm trying to do the following:

Run a specific docker container, `lljvm_work`.
Have it mount a local directory (`../services/c` with its docker mirror in `c_files`).
Run a command there (`lljvm_cc`) to process some files.

What I try to do is:

```
"docker run -v /home/sven/git/cerberos/CerberOS/uJ/services/c/:/c_files -tid lljvm_work llvjm_cc /c_files/test_c_srv.c -lc_support -o test_c_srv -g3"
```

Unfortunately, this gives an error as follows:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: Container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"lljvm-cc\"::executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

I've tried putting the command in quotes and such but cannot get it to work. Any advice?

Addendum:
What I've also tried is the following

```
docker run -v /home/sven/git/cerberos/CerberOS/uJ/services/c/:/c_files -w /c_files -it lljvm_work /bin/bash -c 'lljvm-cc test_c_srv.c -l_c_support -o test_c_srv -g3'
/bin/bash: lljvm-cc: command not found
```

Which, as you can see, does not work as well. This is on Ubuntu.

Doing these steps seperately, with an interactive shell as follows, does work.
E.g.:

```
    ~$ docker run -v /home/sven/git/cerberos/CerberOS/uJ/services/c/:/c_files -w /c_files -it lljvm_work /bin/bash

//Container started

root@6a70a2346951:/c_files# lljvm-cc test_c_srv.c -l_c_support -o test_c_srv -g3

// Desired output is created
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears giving the complete path to the executable does work, though this is not necessary from within the container itself.

Regardless, the following works:

```
docker run -v $(UJ_DIR)/services/c/:/c_files -w /c_files -it lljvm_work \
            /bin/bash -c '../usr/local/lib/lljvm/lljvm-cc $(SRV).c -l_c_support -o $(SRV) -g3'
```